# What is best practice for saving .php files and databases

Tags: php, database, mobile, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have been wondering this for awhile so I thought I would ask. What is best practice for storing .php files and databases when testing and packaging for production when dealing with mobile apps.

This question came about because I wanted to make sure I am doing the follow example right and I really have no clue where I should have these files sitting for both testing and finished product purposes.

What I am working on: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/titanium-user-authentication-part-1--mobile-3728

Comment: I do not get what you are asking for. A folder structure or a webserver to host on?
What has the packing to do with it?

Comment: sorry my terminology may be a bit off.. I am asking about folder structure  when testing as well as when the app is deployed. In this example I am going through (linked in original post) we open the .php located at http://localhost:8889/post_auth.php, so do I just sit that on my desktop?

Comment: You can have the files wherever you want as long as the web server you're using is set to that directory. Note that when deployed you will have to host the PHP files on a publically accessible web host, which you definitely don't want to use your desktop for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you set up your PHP folder structure is up to you, of course.

First thing you need to do is to setup your webserver. Every webserver needs a "root" directory from where it can serve content. If you are running a linux based machine and an Apache server on it, this is most likely `/var/www`.
In that folder you create folders. One for each separate app should keep that thing clean and tidy ;)
In this case we are calling it `my_awesome_app`. The whole path would be `/var/www/my_awesome_app`

In that folder you are as said completely free. Some create a folder called `webroot` where they put all their css, images and js files in. They are then using a `.htaccess` to their app goes directly to that folder. If a css, js or image file is requested and it is found in the folder `webroot` it would be served from there. Every other request would be redirected to an `index.php` which then fires up the real app.

Files for the app would then lie in a folder `src` or `app`.

That was an example of how most of the big frameworks and apps work these days. It only makes sense if you have a lot of code files and other stuff to work with.

For single-file-apps like the one you are currently building in that tutorial you could easily put those files in the `my_awesome_app` folder and try to access them via `localhost:8889/my_awesome_app/post_auth.php`.
That url can be totally different depending on your webserver setup.

If you do not know anything about webservers yet, I suggest you try to find out a little about it. Then to get started quickly, you could use ready-to-use stacks like XAMPP, which is available for Windows, Linux and OS X, and fire one up.
You should get familiar with it first, before you actually proceed with developing, so you can find problems easier later on. ;)

If you want to deploy your app some day, you need those files lying somewhere publicly available. There are different providers for web hosting, which offer this service. You should not host the php files on your PC, because if you turn that thing off, your app goes down. ;)

Comment: Thanks! That was a great read and I feel like I have  afar better understanding now.

Comment: You are very welcome. I thought it might be too complicated, but if you got it all, I was obviously wrong ^^